# WPF XAML Grid.Effect -> DropShadowEffect -> BlurRadius, ShadowDepth

Tags: wpf

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста!
[image: Есть код:]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать стиль-триггер к данному гриду, чтобы при наведении мышки на него (и изображение) ShadowDepth & BlurRadius меняли свое значение (в большую сторону). А при отведении мыши - возвращались в изначальное состояние.

Я написал стиль, приложение компилируется, запускается, но при непосредственном наведении мышки на элемент - мгновенно вылетает, пишет "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)."
[image: 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавте ваш код как текст.

Comment: только при отладке?

Comment: Немног не понял вопрос. Приложение запускается и работает как обычно, но вылетает в момент взаимодействия с элементом, к которому применен данный триггер.

Answer (score 0):

Исправлено. Удалил Storyboard.TargetName.